# regex accents do not appears

Tags: regex, diacritics

I have this simple code that I need to match some words with accents but its not working like I need.
This is the code

```
<?
    $ab=("BÉLICA HOL");
    preg_match_all("/[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ\.]+\b/", $ab,$match_mayusculas);
    print_r($match_mayusculas);

?>
```

The result is this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => BÃ‰LICA [1] => HOL ) ) 
Why?

If I do this
$ab=utf8_decode("BÉLICA HOL");
The result is Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => LICA [2] => HOL ) ) 
Where is my mistake?

Really thanks

Comment: And what does `utf8_decode($match_mayusculas[0][0])` print?

Comment: `preg_match_all("/[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ\.]+\b/u", $ab,$match_mayusculas);`

Comment: /u? What is this for?

Comment: @user2088434 [unicode modifier](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Your file have to be stored in utf-8.

Comment: @user2088434 also make sure you have utf-8 encoding selected in browser - or force it using `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

This works
utf8_decode($match_mayusculas[0][0])
Thanks sp00m